# Comparing .NET instances in native code via GCHandle.ToIntPtr()

Tags: .net

When I use `GCHandle.Alloc(o)` and `GCHandle.ToIntPtr()`, I get a fixed address to a .NET object that can be used to deference later from native code. This is fine and dandy.

However, at a later point in time, this same object could be sent to native again. I have no notion of any previously allocated `GCHandle` types, and must allocate it again. This is fine as well.

The problem is that I need to keep track of unique instances in native code. I can't compare the `System.IntPtr` returned from `GCHandle`'s that were created, because they are different (not surprised).

Is there some way in native code for me to compare two `void*` types that were each `GCHandle.Alloc`'d independently?

Comment: Is there a reason why the managed side can't be modified to "help" the native side more?

Comment: I need to store all the ```void*``` instances in a map. When .NET sends me another pinned type, I need to check if it exists. I could iterate on each item in the map and pass invoke a marshalled .NET delegate that asks "bool isHandleTheSame" and let .NET dereference and compare, but that would require a PInvoke for every item for each lookup. If that map grows, perf would be horrible.

Comment: GCHandle.ToIntPtr() does not do what you think it does.  It returns the handle of the GCHandle, not a pointer to the object.  A single .NET object can have multiple GCHandles, and are quite likely to do so in your scenario, so the identity check is doomed to fail.  Only Object.ReferenceEquals() can give you what you want, it requires managed code.  You'll need to think of another scheme, none is obvious from the brief question but is liable to deteriorate to pinning the object so you can use GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject().  Not good.

Comment: @HansPassant, yup, I had to rethink how this is done. xanatos's answer/coments gave me direction on the correct route to take. It involves tracking the instances in .NET and passing a delegate to native code to so that native code could "lookup" an already existing instance.

Comment: Maybe you ought to steer the managed code to always go through code that uses `Dictionary<object, int>`.  In other words, have it do the identity check first so your native code doesn't have to check.

Comment: Exactly where I ended up, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GCHandle.ToIntPtr()` isn't unique even for the same object. Sadly internally the `GCHandle.ToIntPtr()` doesn't check if there is already the same object in the internal table it uses, and so for each GCHandle it returns a distinct `IntPtr`. No easy solution here.

You could put an ID inside them (because there is no unique object identifier pre-built in managed objects). Clearly you could even keep the managed object pinned and then pass its "real" address with `GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject()`. In this way the GC wouldn't move it. This is doable only for pinnable objects (that are a subset of all the object types of .NET). Note that pinning an object for a long time is a little frowned upon, because it makes the work of the GC harder. No other simple way.

In the end the accepted solution was to handle "manually" the assignment of an identifier: store in a (probably `static`) `Dictionary<,>`/`ConcurrentDictionary<,>`/`ConditionalWeakTable<,>` a list of objects that are passed to native code plus an identifier. The first two will keep a strong reference to the objects stored within, so that the GC won't collect them, the third one will keep a weak reference, so that the GC can collect them if the object isn't referenced anymore. Then create a method that uses the collection and then calls the native method.

I'll add some (totally untested) code to do this (two versions, strong and weak reference):

```
// Strong-reference of the tracked objects: they won't be freed by .NET
// Not thread safe against adding/removing the same key from two different threads!
public class ManagedObjectTracker<TKey> where TKey : class
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, IntPtr> dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, IntPtr>();
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<IntPtr, TKey> reverseDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<IntPtr, TKey>();
    private long lastId;

    // Will always return a handle!
    public bool TryAdd(TKey key, out IntPtr handle)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
        }

        bool added = false;

        handle = dictionary.GetOrAdd(key, x =>
        {
            // No guarantee lastId will be contiguous. Some values could be discarded by GetOrAdd
            // if there is heavy concurrency
            added = true;
            return (IntPtr)Interlocked.Increment(ref lastId);
        });

        if (added)
        {
            reverseDictionary[handle] = key;
        }

        return added;
    }

    public bool TryGetKey(IntPtr handle, out TKey key)
    {
        return reverseDictionary.TryGetValue(handle, out key);
    }

    public bool TryGetHandle(TKey key, out IntPtr handle)
    {
        return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out handle);
    }

    public bool TryRemoveByKey(TKey key, out IntPtr handle)
    {
        if (dictionary.TryRemove(key, out handle))
        {
            reverseDictionary.TryRemove(handle, out key);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool TryRemoveByHandle(IntPtr handle, out TKey key)
    {
        if (reverseDictionary.TryRemove(handle, out key))
        {
            dictionary.TryRemove(key, out handle);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

// Weak-reference of the tracked objects: they won't be freed by .NET
// Not thread safe against adding/removing the same key from two different threads!
public class WeakManagedObjectTracker<TKey> where TKey : class
{
    private readonly ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, SelfDisposingGCHandle> dictionary = new ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, SelfDisposingGCHandle>();

    // Will always return a handle!
    public bool TryAdd(TKey key, out IntPtr handle)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
        }

        SelfDisposingGCHandle handle2 = dictionary.GetOrCreateValue(key);

        if (handle2.IntPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            handle2.Swap(key);
            handle = handle2.IntPtr;
            return true;
        }

        handle = handle2.IntPtr;
        return false;
    }

    public bool TryGetKey(IntPtr handle, out TKey key)
    {
        GCHandle handle2 = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(handle);

        key = (TKey)handle2.Target;

        return key != null;
    }

    public bool TryGetHandle(TKey key, out IntPtr handle)
    {
        SelfDisposingGCHandle handle2;

        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out handle2))
        {
            handle = IntPtr.Zero;
            return false;
        }

        handle = handle2.IntPtr;
        return true;
    }

    public bool TryRemoveByKey(TKey key, out IntPtr handle)
    {
        if (TryGetHandle(key, out handle))
        {
            dictionary.Remove(key);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool TryRemoveByHandle(IntPtr handle, out TKey key)
    {
        if (TryGetKey(handle, out key))
        {
            dictionary.Remove(key);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private sealed class SelfDisposingGCHandle : IDisposable
    {
        public GCHandle handle;

        public SelfDisposingGCHandle()
        {

        }

        public SelfDisposingGCHandle(object value)
        {
            handle = GCHandle.Alloc(value, GCHandleType.Weak);
        }

        public IntPtr IntPtr
        {
            get
            {
                return GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle);
            }
        }

        public GCHandle Swap(object value)
        {
            GCHandle handle2 = handle;
            handle = GCHandle.Alloc(value, GCHandleType.Weak);
            return handle2;
        }

        ~SelfDisposingGCHandle()
        {
            if (handle.IsAllocated)
            {
                handle.Free();
            }
        }

        // Questo codice viene aggiunto per implementare in modo corretto il criterio Disposable.
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (handle.IsAllocated)
            {
                handle.Free();
            }

            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The idea here is that given an `object` we will get a handle of type `IntPtr` that can be passed to native code, and given an `IntPtr` we can get the `object`. The first version (`ManagedObjectTracker<>`) will keep alive the tracked objects. Its implementation generates unique `IntPtr`s that aren't memory addresses but simply auto-incrementing ids. The second version (`WeakManagedObjectTracker<>`) won't keep alive the tracked objects, that can be freed by the GC, and saves the `GCHandle` of the object (with `GCHandleType.Weak`).

Comment: The IntPtr is different, even when doing ```GCHandle.Alloc``` on an already pinned type. So, it isn't that the object is being move around so I get a different IntPtr. It is that the runtime is returning a unique IntPtr that the runtime uses internally to match to a unique instance.

Comment: @PaulKnopf The `ToIntPtr()` return an handle to the `GCHandle`, not to the object. You need `AddrOfPinnedObject()` to get the address of the object.

Comment: When I try to create a GCHandle from a regular object with the "Pinned" option, I get an error: "An instance with nonprimitive (non-blittable) members cannot be pinned."

It works if I give it a struct. It looks like .NET won't ever pin plain-old CLR objects?

Comment: @PaulKnopf :-) yep :-) `GCHandle.ToIntPtr()` should be used this way: you get an `IntPtr`, pass to native code, the native code pass it back to managed code, the managed code does a `GCHandle.FromIntPtr` and then a `GCHandle.Target`.

Comment: I not sure you are understanding this "non-blittable" error I'm going. Take a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/pauldotknopf/116bc508c2b0a31561b6d113ccb514c6

Comment: @PaulKnopf Add a `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]`

Comment: Ah man, this won't work. I need this to work with arbitrary objects that I don't have control over. Back to the drawing board!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176149/discussion-between-xanatos-and-paul-knopf).

Comment: @PaulKnopf I've added two versions of an object tracker that associates an `IntPtr` to an object.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am currently working on a solution now: https://github.com/pauldotknopf/net-core-qml/tree/temp/reuse-net-handle

I will let you know when I am finished if you are interested in seeing what I landed with.

And again, thanks a lot. I couldn't have found an approach without you!